# Symfony and ISO-8859-1

Tags: symfony, character-encoding

There's this app where I need the responses generated by Symfony to use ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, because of backward compatibility issues.

The thing is, Symfony adds a header at `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::prepare()` telling the user that the content is in whatever encoding `$this->charset` contains at that moment, and for me this is always UTF-8, regardless of me changing config.yml to

```
framework:
    charset:         ISO-8859-1
...
```

Isn't this the purpose of this setting? And if not, what's this setting for? How can I instruct Symfony to add an ISO-8859-1 header instead of UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with Symfony 2.1 you have to add a getCharset method to your AppKernel, like this:

```
/**
 * Get the framework charset
 *
 * @return string The charset
 */
public function getCharset()
{
    return 'ISO-8859-1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use latin 1 instead. This works for me.